# Will the default value be used if a windows registry key does not exist?

Tags: windows, registry, default-value

I have two identical Windows machines. One machine (let's say A) has a Windows system registry key configured and a value is set to the registry key default value. The other machine (let's say B) does not have the registry key at all.

I wonder:

1. Whether the default value of the registry key will be taken into consideration by the Windows system of Machine B, and Machine A and B behave the same way? or
2. Whether the corresponding feature/function related to the registry key will be disabled/unavailable on Machine B?

Thanks!

Comment: It is unclear what mechanism Machine B could psychically use to determine a registry key configuration from Machine A.

Comment: A and B are two separated individual boxes having the same Windows OS installed. There is no connection between them.

Comment: Then it seems unlikely that system B can read a registry key from system A.

Comment: Sorry for not making my questions clear.

Let's me rephrase my question:

On a Windows box, if a system registry key does not exist, will the Windows system take the default value of the registry key when performing related functions, or the  the related functions will become unavailable at all?

Comment: It is completely up to the code that reads the key to decide what to do if the key is not there. There is a "default value" but that is the value that is created by default when the key is created, not a value to use if the key is missing.